# Cannot change the variable's value in my loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, jgrasp

I've never made a loop before and  have to for a project.
Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Population
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int dailyPopInc=-1;
        System.out.print("What is the starting number of organisms? ");
        int population = kb.nextInt();
        if (population>1){System.out.print("What is the daily population increase as a percentage? ");
            dailyPopInc= kb.nextInt();}
        else System.out.println("Error");
        int daysMultiplied=0;
        if (dailyPopInc>=0){System.out.print("How many days will they multiply? ");
            daysMultiplied= kb.nextInt();}
        int k=0;
        for (k=1;k<daysMultiplied;k++){
            population= population + population*(dailyPopInc/100);
            System.out.println("The the amount of population on day "+k+" is " + population);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting things like 
"The amount of population on day 1 is 89" and it only changes the day value.

The population never changes. Can somebody please show me my mistakes?

Comment: This has to do with integer division. `dailyPopInc/100` will result in `0` unless `dailyPopInc >= 100` since the fractional part gets discarded.

Comment: Your script is compiling and returns something. Everything else we have to guess because we don't know what it is supposed to do. Add your inputted values might help and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify these lines:

```
 double population = kb.nextInt();
 population= population + population*(dailyPopInc/100.0);
```

It is because dailyPopInc/100 as an integer is always 0.

Comment: How do I make the output a whole number. What you said worked just now its a decimal

Comment: `System.out.println("The the amount of population on day "+k+" is " + Math.round(population));`